# Correct use of repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, statsmodels

I have a repeated measures experiment with the following (simplified) dataframe.

```
subject-id  situation    measured-rate (events per hour over 24hr period)
  A          light        1.2
  B          light        1.1
  C          light        0.9
  D          light        1.1
  A           dusk        1.9
  B           dusk        1.8
  C           dusk        1.8
  D           dusk        1.6
  A           dark        2.3
  B           dark        2.1
  C           dark        2.6
  D           dark        2.5
```

I need to compute the statistical significance among all three distributions, `light`, `dusk`, `dark` and between just `dusk` and `dark`. To be absolutely clear, this is the plot I'm expecting to generate:

```
  ____**_____
       __*___        
            _
       _   | |      y - mean of light, dusk, dark, respectively
  _   | |  | |
_|_|__|_|__|_|__
light dusk dark
```

I'm using `statsmodels.stats.anova.AnovaRM` to perform a Repeated Measures ANOVA.

I've coded it as seen below, but I'm a bit fuzzy about the correct use of `subject` and `within`, and have been having a hard time [following this example](https://www.marsja.se/repeated-measures-anova-in-python-using-statsmodels/).

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.stats.anova import AnovaRM

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
df_dusk_dark_only = df[df['situation'] != 'light']

# for all 3 distributions
AnovaRM(
  data=df, 
  depvar='measured-rate', 
  subject='subject-id', 
  within=['situation']
).fit()

# and df_dusk_dark_only has situation == 'light' filtered out
AnovaRM(
  data=df_dusk_dark_only, 
  depvar='measured-rate', 
  subject='subject-id', 
  within=['situation']
).fit()
```

I'm not confident that I am setting that up correctly. If it is correct I'd like validation from someone who is more experienced with using ANOVAs, or help understanding the proper use of the `AnovaRM` function.

I have a measure from each subject for each situation.

Comment: Start with reading `help(AnovaRM)` to understand the parameters and returns of `AnovaRM`.

Comment: The documentation is maddeningly simplistic for someone struggling to understand. `subject: str - Specify the subject id` and `within: list - The within-subject factors`. It's the fundamental stats concepts as applied to my problem that I'm struggling with. Even the linked tutorial wasn't enough to clarify it for me. I have questions like whether subject and within should be swaped? Is the dataframe set up properly in this case? Are there limitations to AnovaRM that make it a bad fit for my use case? I have a result, but I don't know how to validate that it's correct.

Comment: Some options are (1) read the [source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/stats/anova.html#AnovaRM), (2) compare to [other software](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/04/repeated-measures-of-anova-in-r-complete-tutorial/), or (3) do the calculation yourself and then see what `AnovaRM` did in comparison.

Comment: One point to consider (in general) from docs: `This implementation currently only supports fully balanced designs.`.

Comment: Another option is to raise this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels). Poor documentation matters.